# Accessing pillar data in custom grain module in Salt

Tags: python, salt-stack

This might not be the best way to go about setting custom grains, but I want set up custom grains "roles" by reading pillar data. This will allow easy editing in YAML syntax for the pillar data while the custom grains is set as highest priority and not overwritten by other configs.

My question is how to access the pillar data in the custom grains python file in the `_grain` dir?

I've tried:

```
hosts = __salt__['pillar.get']('hosts',None)
```

but I get an error:

```
NameError: global name '__salt__' is not defined
```

Even when I add

```
import salt.client
import salt.config
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look at Salts built-in grains (more specifically, the [`core.py` grain module](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/develop/salt/grains/core.py)). In there, they actually define the `__salt__` object themselves ([line 44ff.](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/develop/salt/grains/core.py#L48)):

```
__salt__ = {
    'cmd.run': salt.modules.cmdmod._run_quiet,
    'cmd.retcode': salt.modules.cmdmod._retcode_quiet,
    'cmd.run_all': salt.modules.cmdmod._run_all_quiet,
    'smbios.records': salt.modules.smbios.records,
    'smbios.get': salt.modules.smbios.get,
}
```

In theory (untested!), you should also be able to do this in your custom grain. When you need the `pillar.get` module, you'll need to import a different function, of course:

```
import salt.modules.pillar

__salt__ = {
    'pillar.get': salt.modules.pillar.get
}
```

Of course, you can also just call `salt.modules.pillar.get('hosts', None)` directly without bothering to create the `__salt__` dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried to user salt.modules.pillar.get but I get an error about __opts__ not defined! I remember I read somewhere that you need to define this options variable somehow but I can't seem to find out how. any ideas?